# How to wait until all threads are ready before start them

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x

I have this working script:

```
import socket, threading

def loop():
    global threads
    get_host = "GET " + url + " HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: " + url + "\r\n"
    accept = "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\nAccept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\n"
    connection = "Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n"
    useragent = "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36\r\n"
    request = get_host + useragent + accept + connection + "\r\n"
    for x in range(800): 
        send().start() 

class send(threading.Thread):

    def run(self):
        self.requestdefault()
    def requestdefault(self):
        while True:
            try:
                s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
                s.connect((str(url), int(urlport)))
                s.send (str.encode(request))
                print ("Request sent!")
            except:
                pass

loop()
```

How can I let wait program before all threads are ready before starting them end send request?

Comment: What do you mean by “ready”?

Comment: I mean, instead of start one, then one, then another one,ecc.. Wait until them charge, and then start them simoultaneously

Comment: The thing is, there is no such thing as simultaneously. Your computer can only run as many threads as you have CPU cores at once (4, most probably). It simulates the ability to run more by interrupting them and running them one after the other, switching a few hundred times per second to give the illusion of simultaneity. It gets even worse in python, where the GIL limits this to only one thread advancing at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need some notification mechanics. I think you should try event object like below snippet:

```
import threading
import time

event=threading.Event()

def main_thread():
    time.sleep(10)
    event.set() # notify, enable worker thread run

def worker_thread():
    event.wait()
    print threading.currentThread().name +" running \n"

if __name__=='__main__':
    for i in xrange(0,2):
        t=threading.Thread(target=worker_thread)
        t.start()
    main_thread()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have many threads that need to run setup functions then wait until all the other threads are set up, I would use the [Barrier object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Barrier). A thread can call `barrier.wait()` and will wait until all threads have called the wait method to continue in their execution. Here's an example script:

```py
import threading

def main():
    number_of_threads = 3 # or any n
    barrier = threading.Barrier(number_of_threads)
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=thread1, args=(barrier))
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=thread2, args=(barrier))
    t3 = threading.Thread(target=thread3, args=(barrier))

    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    t3.start()

    t1.join()
    t2.join()
    t3.join()

def thread1(barrier):
   x = 1+2
   barrier.wait()
   x = x*x

def thread2(barrier):
   y = 1+2
   barrier.wait()
   y = y*y

def thread3(barrier):
   z = 1+2
   barrier.wait()
   z = z*z
```

In this script, each thread will set its x, y, or z before continuing to do the calculation.

Note: As @spectras said, this does not guarantee the threads will continue to execute at the same time. You should never use threads with the assumption that they will execute in a certain order after the `barrier.wait()` function returns.